# Want to build Online Scheduler Web Application, which is better to use GWT or RoR ? and why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gwt

I want to build Online Scheduler Web Application, where user can manage their schedule of their days, which is better to use GWT or RoR ? and why? and the one with fast development time and fast performance is better..

Comment: any other suggestion, experts ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not combine GWT and RoR? You can use both, GWT for your frontend and RoR (REST api) for your backend.

Comment: wow, sounds good. do you have any example or reference for it?

Comment: I don't have any reference on how to achieve this (maybe I should write a blog post) but you can see it in practice here: http://www.rento.gr/places/rentals/athens (greek only). Rento is an app we have developed for accommodation search in the city of Athens. It used to be rails only, but now what you see in the front-end is a pure GWT 2.0.4 app which communicates with a rails backend.

Comment: wow it's a very awesome web app! wonder how can i learn it, do you know about http://code.google.com/p/gwt-rails/ ?? Yeah, i will be waiting for it! and please let me know what is your blog addrs :D

Comment: Yeah, I 've seen gwt-rails before but I don't believe is active anymore (no source update since 16.02.2010 :S).
I started a blog a few days ago, http://jgonian.wordpress.com/ to share some handy tips around GWT development..Stay tuned If you are interested :)

Comment: yeah, i just visit it too. okay thanks for your enlightenment, i will stay tuned in your blog, hope to see the gwt + RoR post in there soon :D

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely a matter of personal taste, and whichever you're more comfortable with. Robust, full-featured web applications can be (and are) written in lots of languages.